# Android - Check if startup service is running

Tags: java, android

My application run a service on startup (Service.java). I need to know when you start the application manually (in the Main.java) if my service is still running. Following my code on Main.java in onCreate:

```
if(isMyServiceRunning(Service.class)){
   System.out.println("Still running");
}
```

isMyServiceRunning function:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

The problem is that `isMyServiceRunning` returns false even if the service is still running! How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using that approach, I'll create a boolean member in the application object with getter/setter. In service onCreate() you'll set the flag, and then you can query that flag from any point inside your activity.

In your application object class (assumed to be MyApplication.java):

```
private boolean serviceRunning = false;

public boolean isServiceRunning() {
    return serviceRunning;
}

public void setServiceRunning(boolean serviceRunning) {
    this.serviceRunning = serviceRunning;
}
```

Then, inside service's onCreate():

```
((MyApplication)getApplication()).setServiceRunning(true);
```

Then, to check the state of the service from any point in your activity:

```
if(((MyApplication)getApplication()).isServiceRunning()){
    //do the stuff here
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you post an example code please?

Comment: Binding to a service is a complex task for just to know if its running. Also querying the ActivityManager will require additional permissions.

Comment: You need to create it in your AndroidManifest.xml, and then create the java file (Application Tag inside the manifest).